# Not Exists clause -Query

Tags: sql, data-science, presto

I am using a NOT EXSITS clause in my query and wanted to make sure it was working correctly since I was getting lesser rows than expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT offer.courier_uuid,
                offer.region_uuid,
                offer.offer_time_local,
                Cast(scores.acceptance_rate AS DECIMAL(5, 3)) AS acceptance_rate
FROM integrated_delivery.trip_offer_fact offer
JOIN integrated_product.driver_score_v2 scores ON offer.courier_uuid = scores.courier_id
AND offer.region_uuid = scores.region_id
AND offer.business_day BETWEEN date '2019-04-04' AND date '2019-04-07'
AND scores.extract_dt = 20190331
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT NULL
   FROM source_cassandra_courier_scheduling.assigned_block_by_id_v2 sched
   JOIN source_cassandra_delivery.region r ON sched.region_id = r.id
   WHERE offer.courier_uuid = sched.courier_id
     AND offer.offer_time_local >= date_parse(date_format(AT_TIMEZONE("start",r.time_zone),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
     AND offer.offer_time_local <= date_parse(date_format(AT_TIMEZONE("end",r.time_zone),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
     AND element_at(sched.state,-1) = 'ASSIGNED')
ORDER BY 3
```

Is there anything wrong with my not exists clause? I am only asking since I am getting back lesser rows than expected. The not exists caluse contains a time conversion but i dont think that would affect anything.

I am trying to get all possible ids and their offer times that do NOT EXIST in the scheduled shifts table. I wanted confirm if the way I have the NOT EXISTS clause is correct or if there is something else I would need that would correctly pull all records that exist or not exist in that shed table?

Comment: If the code runs, there is nothing "wrong" with it.  You haven't provided sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic, or any useful description (other than some rows might be missing).

Comment: Sorry I will add logic behind it, the expected output would just be the columns listed under select distinct

Comment: Simple way to test: replace the `NOT EXISTS` by `exists` (or change/remove the date interval conditions)